# Allow users to line break with enter key in MySQL form submission

Tags: html, css, textbox, line-breaks

I am making a form where users can submit text in a html text area, and that is stored in MySQL and displayed on another page. But I'm running into issues with allowing users to make line-breaks using their enter key. I've seen numerous websites that do this, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are coding using php you can just echo the stored textarea value from database like this:

```
echo nl2br($my_textarea_value);
```